# OpenLayers and Geoserver, getting Layer's lat and long

Tags: angular, coordinates, openlayers, center, geoserver

Here is the scenario:

I have a VectorTileLayer built with VectorTileSource

```
    this.vectorTileSource = new VectorTileSource({
      format: new GeoJSON(),
      url: 'http://localhost:8090/geoserver/smartzone/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=work:name&outputFormat=application/json'
    });

this.vtLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
  declutter: true,
  source: this.vectorTileSource,
  style:someStyle
});
```

Now I want to display the layer on the map:

```
this.map = new Map({
  target: this.viewMap.nativeElement,
  overlays: [this.overlay],
  layers: this.vtLayer,
  view: new View({
    center: ???
    zoom: 10.2
  })
});
```

??? - how do I get coordinates(lat/long) for the center?
Manually I can grab them from layer properties in GeoServer UI

[image]

But I need to grab it somehow using OpenLayers scripts...

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the [layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html#getExtent):

```
layer.getExtent().getCenter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how its done:

```
//we do it on change event for the vector source
    this.wfsVectorSource.on('change', (evt)=>{
      var source=evt.target;
      if(source.getState() === 'ready'){ //then when its ready
          this.map.getView().fit(source.getExtent(), this.map.getSize() as any);
          //source.getExtent() gets you coordinates for the layer
      }
    });
```